# ADF Default Columns

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

ADF Copy task:

Importing flat files with wildcard *.txt, some files have 18 cols, some have 24.
SQL table sink has 24 cols.

Fails because it does not find a mapping for cols 19-24.
Can i default the mapping of the last 6 cols to NULL when no value is found ?

EDIT:

I copied my source to blob and used a dataflow with schema drift instead. I can connect to my source and can see that it writes parquet files to the staging folder, but after calculating the rows the workflow fails with error:

Operation on target Dataflow1 failed: {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'nsodevsynapse': Unable to stage data before write. Check configuration/credentials of storage","Details":"org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This operation is not permitted on a non-empty directory.\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.delete(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2607)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.delete(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2617)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.deleteFile(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2657)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$2.execute(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2391)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureFileSystemThreadPoolExecutor.executeParallel(AzureFileSystemThreadPoolExecutor.java:223)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.deleteWithoutAuth(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2403)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.delete(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2453)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.delete(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1936)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter."}

My sink is using a sql account to connect, i can connect to sql using that account. I can write edit SQL tables using that account.

the managed instance has owner permissions on the storage account.

Answer (score 1):

You can load data using the `dataflow` activity by enabling “**Allow schema drift**” in source and sink transformations and it will automatically default the values to NULL when not passed.

**Source files:**

[image] [image]

**Dataflow:**

•   In `source` and `Sink`, enable "Allow schema drift" if the source schema changes often.

[image]

[image]

•   **Add mapping** to map all source columns to destination.

[image]

**Destination SQL table:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works but fails. 

Operation on target Dataflow1 failed: {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'devsynapse': Unable to stage data before write. Check configuration/credentials of storage","Details":"org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This operation is not permitted on a non-empty directory.\n\tat 

the account i am connecting to the ADLS with has contributor on ADLS, and CONTROL permissions on the sql db.

Comment: what are your source and sink connection types?

Comment: ADLS Gen2 Blob container to Synapse SQL DW. It was suggested to change the linked service for the storage to ADLSG2 instead of blob, but i cannot create the linked service. the test gives me this error

Error details
Error code
24200
Details
ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: An error occurred while sending the request.. Account: 'devsynapsedatalake'.. An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: check this link if it is of any help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage#managed-identity

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention i changed the solution somewhat - to copy the files from onprem to azure storage first, and then to copy from storage to sql using dataflow transform. i was able to connect to the source and sink, but the load was failing with an error about the staging. It was suggested to change the linked service from blob to ADLSgen2 but that gives me a new error. 
Error Code 24200
ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: An error occurred while sending the request. Account: 'devsynapsedatalake'.. An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: If possible, can you update the original post and add your linked service connections and error details screenshots?